# How can I access Objects in this JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm currently working on a command line interface to show random quotes, found an API to consume quotes from, problem is the JSON is returned as an array like this

```js
[{"ID":648,"title":"Jeff Croft","content":"<p>Do you validate other  <\/p>\n","link":"https:\/\/quotesondesign.com\/jeff-croft\/","custom_meta":{"Source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/cdharrison.com\/2009\/06\/notes-from-jeff-crofts-grids-css-standards-and-tomfoolery\/\">presentation<\/a>"}}]
```

What I want to access is the `content`:`<p>Do you validate other<\/p>` which is the quote I want

Comment: `theArray[0].content` or generally `theArray[ index ].content`. To loop use `forEach` like: `theArray.forEach(function(o) {  /*use o.content;*/  });`

Comment: I've tried storing the parsed Json in a variable and accessing it by key

Comment: Result returns undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets assume your json is returned into a variable RESULT:

```
var resultObj = JSON.parse(RESULT);
var theDataYouWant = resultObj[0].content;
```

The content is now in the theDataYouWant variable.

Comment: Just to be clear here, the reason you were having issues was because you were treating the JSON that was being returned as an object. The key to my solution working for you is that the first line parses the JSON into an object. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a Array of JSON objects you can access it by

```js
    var data = [
      {
        "ID": 648,
        "title": "Jeff Croft",
        "content": "<p>Do you validate other  <\/p>\n",
        "link": "https:\/\/quotesondesign.com\/jeff-croft\/",
        "custom_meta": {
          "Source": "<a href=\"http:\/\/cdharrison.com\/2009\/06\/notes-from-jeff-crofts-grids-css-standards-and-tomfoolery\/\">presentation<\/a>"
        }
      }
    ];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i].content);
    }
```

Comment: Works @Zanko, and also great for loops if I wanted to work with multiple quotes. Initially parsing the JSON  returned `object Object`, storing in a variable, didn't know why i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var A = [{"ID":648,"title":"Jeff Croft","content":"<p>Do you validate other  <\/p>\n","link":"https:\/\/quotesondesign.com\/jeff-croft\/","custom_meta":{"Source":"<a href=\"http:\/\/cdharrison.com\/2009\/06\/notes-from-jeff-crofts-grids-css-standards-and-tomfoolery\/\">presentation<\/a>"}}]

A.map(a => a.content)
//gives: ["<p>Do you validate other  </p>"]
```

I like this approach because your json could be huge, and you might want all of the content items.

but if you want just the first one, you can always destructure (es6):

```
const [first] = A.map(a => a.content)
first; // gives => "<p>Do you validate other  </p>"
```

of course, I'm assuming more than "one" data set. You can always use the [0] to get the first item (like others alluded in this post)

```
A.map(a => a.content)[0]
//gives: "<p>Do you validate other  </p>"
```

Comment: Your approach has got me learning more about arrow functions and ES6 in general. Tried with a larger JSON with multiple content items and noticed some performance improvement also

Comment: cool.. give me an upvote! lololol... gotta love those extra rep points :-). Glad to help. Yeah, es6 --> move towards functional, you'll love it!